# how to scale user time series data in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, logging, system-design

my requirement is to store time series data from each user and provide search on this time series data. The time series data is complex and is not just time and a float, it's more like time and a json object over which filter will be applied.

So was wondering what might be the best way to approach this requirement. currently am just pushing everything into a single collection in mongod.

I know that this wont scale at all. I tried looking for products having similar requirements like loggly and sentry. But i couldn't find any docs about their architecture or storage details.

I would appreciate it you guys can point in the right direction, like what are the things i need to keep in mind, what trade off's would i have to make etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo DB is document store, it is not right for time series dataset and especially search on time series data.
Two options

1. If you are looking at search - for JSON associated with timestamp - Elastic search
2. If you are looking to persist time series data and query it - than Cassandra  or any other time series DB